# "trouble processing "javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.class" while compiling ROSJAVA

Tags: android, gradle, ros

I'm compiling ROSJAVA and this message appears when I'm deploying the software to my smartphone:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pre-dex '/Users/gianig/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/3136ca936f64c9d68529f048c2618bd356bf85c9/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar' to '/Users/gianig/Dropbox/desarrollo/baro/BAROCAR/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dex/debug/folders/1000/10/xml-apis-1.0.b2_6f6c2677a7068c74c1325d5d775568e757376d68'


Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Error:trouble processing "javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.class":
Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
Error:when not building a core library.
Error:This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
Error:in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Error:Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
Error:core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
Error:going on.
Error:However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
Error:namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
Error:from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
Error:assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
Error:compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
Error:It is also often of questionable legality.
Error:If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
Error:appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
Error:distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
Error:the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
Error:If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
Error:building an application, then be forewarned that your application
Error:will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
Error:prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
Error:application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
Error:system. You will be to blame for this problem.
Error:If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
Error:core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
Error:repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
Error:your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
Error:conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
Error:you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
Error:that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
Error:lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
Error:1 error; aborting
```

Comment: Just because it's a Java library does not mean it works on Android. `Error:from a non-Android virtual machine project`

Comment: Yes i undestand but this library rosjava is a standard library to use in android devices.

Comment: According to what? The error is that `javax.*` package isn't intended to be used in Android

Comment: You'll have to be more clear about how you're compiling and which part of this process you are stuck at http://wiki.ros.org/android?distro=kinetic